# what is the best way to extract variables with '=' from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to extract the variables names from a string like this: `"foo=valor bar=second"`, and so on.

To return:

```
{ 
   foo: "valor", 
   bar: "second",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Regex Look Aheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for a variable name that is preceded by an `=` symbol

```js
var str = "foo=valor bar=second";
var varRegex = /\w+(?=(\s)*(\=))/g;
var valueRegex = /(?<=(\=)[\s'"]*)\w+/g;

var varArr = str.match(varRegex);
var valueArr = str.match(valueRegex);
console.log(valueArr);

let obj = {};
for(let i in varArr) {
  obj[varArr[i]] = valueArr[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: so fast! how it could be maintaining the name of the variables in an object? to return: { foo: "valor", bar: "second" }

Comment: _"preceded by"_ would be `=value` -- I think you mean _"followed by"_ like `var=`

Comment: this is really awesome how fast and good you are participating guys, What I need it to build the object given the string. Not an array. So i keep track of the key and value pairs. Thxx!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "foo=valor,bar=second";

var obj = {};

str.split(",").forEach(
     function(item){
     if(item){ 
        var vars = item.split("="); 
        obj[vars[0]] = vars[1] 
      }
 });
 console.log(obj)
```

Comment: this is definitely a solution, but the the answer by @rv7 is shorter

Answer (score 0):

Different approach from the previous answer: You can split the string on spaces and then map the result array, splitting on the equal sign to create your object (left side is property, right side is value)

If you need it your specific format you can reduce it to convert the array into one big object with all the values

```js
let a = "foo=valor bar=second"

console.log(a.split(' ').map((i,v) => { return JSON.parse(`{"${i.split('=')[0]}": "${i.split('=')[1]}"}`);}))


let b = a.split(' ').map((i,v) => { return JSON.parse(`{"${i.split('=')[0]}": "${i.split('=')[1]}"}`);})


console.log(b.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    for (var key in x) acc[key] = x[key];
    return acc;
   }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the quickest answer (in terms of speed of submission), but less regular expressions to maintain and less variables to store.

```
function toJSON(str) {
  const regex = /(\w+)\=(\w+)\s*/g;
  let result = {};
  let match;

  while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    result[match[1]] = match[2];
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(toJSON("foo=valor bar=second"));
```