# set string to var '=' statement using Javascript split function

Tags: javascript, split

Using javascript how to easily get width and height with the following string?

```
 'width="90" height="90"'
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747011/what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-variables-with-from-a-string-in-javascript/52747086#52747086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find a pattern. In this case i'm finding them by groups. Each set of word is a group. You can then access them by position in your pattern.

In this case in my **second** group regex is `(\d*)`, this indicates that there should be a number. This meaning you always need to access the `group[2]` after you checked the pattern

You can do it by doing `matchWidth[2]` and `matchHeight[2]`

```js
var myString = 'width="90" height="39.45"';
var width = /(width=")(\S*)["]/;
var height = /(height=")(\S*)["]/
var matchWidth = width.exec(myString);
var matchHeight = height.exec(myString);
console.log(matchWidth[2]); // 90
console.log(matchHeight[2]); // 39.45
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could split by `"` instead:

```
var str = 'width="90" height="90"';
var pieces = str.split('"');

console.log(pieces)

var width = pieces[1];
var height = pieces[3];
```